# Linux Shell script to add a user with a password from a list

Tags: linux, bash, unix, ubuntu-16.04

I'm trying to modify a script that read usernames/password from a file which is like this:

```
user1 pass1
user2 pass2
user3 pass3
```

I can't get the script to read the space between the users and pass.
What can I use to delimit this space?
This is my code:

```
for row in `cat $1`
do
  if [ $(id -u) -eq 0 ]; then


      username=${row%:*}
      password=${row#*:}
      #echo $username
      #echo $password
```

I know I have to change the stuff in ${row%:*} and ${row%:*}

What do I have to put so it sees the space between user1 pass1 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be easier to split the two fields as you read each line. You can do that with `read`. It's also better to use a `while` loop here (a for loop requires to play with `$IFS` and it would also load the entire file in memory):

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$EUID" -ne 0 ]; then
    echo >&2 "You are not root"
    exit 1
fi

while read -r username password; do
    # do the useradd stuff here
done < "$1"
```

Notice that I also changed `$(id -u)` to `$UID` which should be faster since it does not invoke an external program.

Comment: Put it in a file, e.g. `myscript.sh` (don't forget to add a shebang at the top: `#!/bin/bash`) and then run it like so `./myscript.sh passwords.txt`.

Comment: Got it to read the file. Now how would I add this bit of code to my main script so it can create the users? I edited my main script in the question.